# How to fill a combobox in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagrid view with 10 columns.  It includes 2 checkbox columns followed by a combobox and then a number of text boxes for data entry.  I do not have a database to load the combobox drop down but I do have a variable with 19 rows.  I have tried a number of methods from SO but haven't been able to get this to work correctly so I can load the combobox for the user to select a value.

The code I've been using is like this.  I have tried several different ways that are commented out as well...

```
' Build datagridview row
'
Dim t1 As New DataTable
For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgvMultiSelect.Columns
    t1.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText)
Next

Dim dgvcb As New DataTable
dgvcb.Columns.Add("RunID", GetType(String))

For el = 0 To sRunID.Length - 1
    dgvcb.Columns.Add(sRunID(el))
    RunID.Items.Add(sRunID(el))
Next

'        RunID.DataSource = dgvcb
'        RunID.DataPropertyName = "dgvcb"
'   RunID.DataSource = sRunID
'   RunID.DataPropertyName = "sRunID"

'Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
'DataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk)
'chk.HeaderText = "Check Data"
'chk.Name = "chk"
dgvMultiSelect.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = True
```

The checkbox works fine (it shows as checked) and I was able to set the combobox value to show but clicking on the dropdown does nothing.  I believe the data is in RunID (the column in the dgv.

Comment: I am guessing a `variable with 19 rows` means an array.  If so you could use that as the DataSource for the CBO column

Comment: Yes, an array (sRunID).  I did and that had values in the comboboxs when I debugged but didn't allow the dropdown or show a value.

Comment: I cant quite follow what you are doing or trying to do.  The code shows 2 tables (no arrays) and something else named `RunID` with no definition.  `String` seems the wrong type for something named `...Id`.   If you dont have a DB, you could just add the array to the items collection of the CBOColumn

Comment: Using the RunID.DataSource = sRunID does load the 19 values and I see them but the dropdown doesn't allow any visibility or selection.
RunID is the column in the dgv that is a combobox.  It is in a different form so they are not static values but come from an external program lookup.
RunID is a string as it could contain any combination of letters and numbers.  
sRunID is the array defined outside this code as 
Dim sRunID() As String
and contains the values received from the external program (not a database).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer that worked for me is:  I was referencing the datagridviewCOLUMN and not a datagridviewCOMBOBOXcolumn.  Thanks to Sai Kalyan Kumar Akshinthala!

```
' Build datagridview row

Dim dgvcc As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
dgvcc = dgvMultiSelect.Columns("RunID")

For el = 0 To sRunID.Length - 1
   dgvcc.Items.Add(sRunID(el))
   dgvMultiSelect.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value = sRunID(el)
Next
```

Maybe next time you'll try to understand before voting down.  Such a silly thing this voting down anyway.  It should not reduce reputation.